# what protection is required between op amp and 5v adc?

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, adc, protection, level-shifting

I've created this small circuit to translate voltage drop over a shunt resistor into a usable range for arduino (5v atmega32u4) adc.

This is to measure current out of **and** into (charging) a 12v battery on a boat.
The shunt is low side (connected to Bat-). My circuit has Bat- as Ground, Vin at high side of shunt. The shunt is 75mV at 100A.

The circuit seems to work nicely (though center was ~0.8v below the expected 2.5?)

Question(s):
It should probably be some form of protection in there. If I float Vin, output goes >9v and uC-pins would be unhappy. Is a zener diode enough?

Anything else that's missing? 0.1u caps on input and output?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftPzf0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Don't add a capacitor on an opamp output. You may add a clamp (zener or schottky to 5v) and a series resistor.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question I would power your opamp off a wide input range LDO, even a 7805 would do, versus directly powering on VBAT

Comment: @sstobbe: I'm sorry, what's unclear? I'd like to know how I should prevent the ~12v op-amp circuit from blowing up the 5v uC pins if it gets out of control.

I was thinking about regulating 12v, but figured I would try to compensate for the varying voltage in software (I'm measuring the battery voltage separately)

Comment: Where's the current shunt in your circuit.

Comment: The Sine generator in the schematic will be the current shunt.

Comment: I had thought Vin was your shunt, but then you have res divider up to vbat, vbat will move way more than your shunt

Comment: @sstobbe, the divider up to vbat was for the level shift (maybe I've got this all wrong? :) ) So yes, the vin is the shunt.

Comment: Vbat will change with state of charge and if being charged, but it should be **very** low frequency, and possible to compensate for in software.. But OK, the recommendation for LDO is noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A zener clamp will be sufficient to protect the uP A/D input.

If the measured parameter is an AC signal, capacitors would only remove DC bias. The resulting AC signal or spikes could still exceed the input ratings.